# Change Owner From “root” in VMware's Shared Folder

Tags: vmware, shared-folders, chown

I'm running a `Xubuntu` from a Windows 8 host. I can't change the owner of shared files from `xubuntu` by any `sudo chown ...` command. Is there any other way I can change the owner from the `root` to the `user`? I also have tried to `mount` the shared folder into home directory, still didn't change anything

```
hooman@ubuntu:~/win/meteor$ ls -al
total 20
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Dec 10 19:03 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16384 Dec 11 18:30 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 Dec 10 19:03 simple-todos
hooman@ubuntu:~/win/meteor$
```

I already tried `Sudo chown -v` , `sudo chown -Rv` , etc:

```
hooman@ubuntu:~/win/meteor$ ls -al
total 20
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Dec 10 19:03 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16384 Dec 11 18:30 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 Dec 10 19:03 simple-todos
hooman@ubuntu:~/win/meteor$ sudo chown -v hooman simple-todos/
changed ownership of ‘simple-todos/’ from root to hooman
hooman@ubuntu:~/win/meteor$ ls -al
total 20
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Dec 10 19:03 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16384 Dec 11 18:30 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 Dec 10 19:03 simple-todos
```

Answer (score 0):

On **VirtualBox**, it is a simple fix. Run this first to add user to `vboxsf` group:

```
sudo adduser mysuser vboxsf
```

Then run either the command you were trying, or the one below to change group ownership as well.

```
sudo chown hooman:hooman simple-todos/
```

Add **-R** if you would like to recursively change ownership in the directory.

On **VMWare**, there is a little more to it. Try using this [guide](http://viraj-workstuff.blogspot.com/2013/07/vmware-fusion-permissions-on-shared.html).

Comment: Thanks but didn't work

Comment: @Hooman I have edited my answer, I hope this is more helpful.